# С# Кракозябры при заполнении массива из файла

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь загрузить файл с Ru и En именами

```
string[] name_0 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\file.txt").Take(5100).ToArray();
```

С помощью цикла `for` вывожу их в `textBox` и получаю кракозябры.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как подобное лечить ?

Comment: когда сохраняется файл изменить кодировку ,когда сохраняете данные делаете кодировку.  А когда обратно берёте данные декодируйте тогда не будет проблем проблема от 'ASCII/UNICODE'

Comment: ничего не понял xD
Смотрю Notepad++ и тут только ASCII / UTF-8 / UCS-2
В какой кодировке надо сохранить txt, чтобы без проблем подтягивалось ?

Comment: Используйте 'UTF-8' или 'UNICODE (Standart)'.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в том, что файл записан как UTF-8 без BOM.
BOM - это три байта в начале файла, маркер для приложений, что это UTF-8. В Notepad++ перекодируйте файл в UTF-8 with BOM и должно быть нормально.

Comment: @LevLimin как раз с без BOM стало всё в порядке

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё равно, в какой кодировке записан файл. В .NET нет «кодировки, чтобы всё было без проблем», нужно просто указывать правильную кодировку в коде.

Используйте

```
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251); // <-- подставьте здесь правильную кодировку!
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\file.txt", encoding).Take(5100).ToArray();
```

(Какая конкретно кодировка у вашего файла, мы не знаем. Выясняйте, файл у вас есть.)